# Tools for simulating software-driven PWM

Tags: pwm, simulation, behavioral-source

I want to simulate a software driven PWM. So, I need to program the controller output based on the transient/instantaneous feedback from some part of the circuit in the simulation (i.e. the software logic must run as part of the simulation).

In other words, I basically want to have as simulation input an arbitrary function of the circuit properties itself.

For instance, imagine a PIC controlling a MOSFET, and the output from PIC depends on its analog input from some other part of the circuit. What tools can I use to simulate such circuit? I don't want to simulate the PIC itself, I just want some way to control some digital input signal depending on the instantaneous properties of the simulated circuit.

Comment: Can the dependency be modelled with some discrete parts?

Comment: In theory, yes, because digital circuitry are turing complete, but it can be impractical for complex functions, so I wanted some tool that allowed me to code it in software.

Comment: So my question was how complex it would be and perhaps it can be simplified for the simulation purposes? Otherwise the tools that might exist are rather expensive. Just googled and found [this](http://www.tina.com/) for example. Not sure how good it is..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by software-driven PWM. Are you talking about simulating a bit-banged PWM signal, or simulating a software-controlled varying duty cycle signal such as is found in many control systems? The former makes no sense and the latter is straight-forward.

Comment: I guess I am talking about simulating a bit-banged PWM signal... why it makes no sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it is not very clear what are your requirements.

Anyway, Multisim, which is available for free from National Instruments with some sort of student license, is also a SPICE simulator and among its models has a PIC simulation engine, i.e. you can enter PIC assembly code. I never used it myself, but I knew a couple of people that said it is decent. YMMV

But you say you don't need to simulate the PIC, so maybe you could use [LTspice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/ltspice/info), it is a free professional SPICE simulator. It supports behavioral voltage sources, i.e. sources whose output is modeled by mathematical functions. Excerpts from its help file:

> **B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources Symbol names: BV,
>   BI**
>
> Syntax: Bnnn n001 n002 V= [ic=]
>   + [tripdv=] [tripdt=]
>   + [laplace= [window=]
>   + [nfft=] [mtol=]]

...

> Tripdv and tripdt control step rejection. If the voltage across a
>   source changes by more than tripdv volts in tripdt seconds, that
>   simulation time step is rejected.
>
> Expressions can contain the following:
>
> o Node voltages, e.g., V(n001)
>
> o Node voltage differences, e.g., V(n001, n002)
>
> o Circuit element currents; for example, I(S1), the current through
>   switch S1 or Ib(Q1), the base current of Q1. However, it is assumed
>   that the circuit element current is varying quasi-statically, that is,
>   there is no instantaneous feedback between the current through the
>   referenced device and the behavioral source output. Similarly, any ac
>   component of such a device current is assumed to be zero in a small
>   signal linear .AC analysis.
>
> o The keyword, "time" meaning the current time in the simulation.
>
> o The keyword, "pi" meaning 3.14159265358979323846.
>
> o The following functions:

...

And then lists a lot of functions and operators. Refer to the guide for more details or [this very complete LT WIKI page](http://ltwiki.org/?title=B_sources_%28complete_reference%29).

You can even specify the source behavior using Laplace transforms.

Maybe it can be useful for you: you can enter the schematic of your analog part and model the interactions using behavioral sources.

Comment: Yes, I believe what I wanted was these "behavioral sources". Thanks.